# UIActivityViewController compose window navigation bar color

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

When choosing a sharing option from the activity view such as message or email composing, the navigation bar (or is it a toolbar) and title colours look terrible. The title and status bar items are almost unreadable.

I have tried to change navigation bar and toolbar tint, barTint, background and title colours with no luck. Also tried to toggle between default and light styles.
Changing navigation bar tint colours on the main view itself also renders no difference.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom background image for the navigationbar?  If so, you need to set the background image to nil before presenting the compose sheet.  Something like:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Otherwise,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor WhiteColor]];
```

should work.